# apigility RPC how to get post

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, rpc, laminas-api-tools

I have searched and I have found zero answers, so it must be something simple that eludes me.

When I create an RPC in apigility and the two .php files generate, how do I get the POST/GET data coming from a request so I can start working with it?

```
class StatusController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function statusAction()
    {
        //how do I get the POST received?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('valueName');
```

Also be sure to add the valueName inside the field tab on the apigility service.

Or to retrieve them all at once.

```
$input = $this->getEvent()->getParam('ZF\ContentValidation\InputFilter');
$params = $input->getValues();
```

If you are cache your module class map and config be sure to delete them as well I have forgot that on more then one occasion.